# Drupal CKEditor format dropdown wrapping all text not just the selected text with html

Tags: html, drupal, ckeditor, output, rte

In Drupal the CKEditor, when I highlight a word and apply any element from the Format drop down(Formatted, address, h1-h6 etc...) it is being applied to the whole block of text.

i.e.
In May, Joe Smith, Chairman, President & CEO, hosted more than 1,700 business team members.

When I select Joe Smith and apply a `<h4>` to it, the entire sentence is wrapped in the `<h4>`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is because that's how HTML works. You can't have a header inside a paragraph, the header is its own element. H stands for header -- these elements need to be standalone, on their own line. You can style them to behave as if they are inline, but the actual HTML of it simply can't be that way, it's invalid. The format dropdown is for selecting wrappers. If you're just wanting to make something bold, or if you use the "Styles" dropdown instead (you may have to add it) then it will work as you expect. But the headers can't work like that.